# Realtek RTL8191SE crashes with intense networking

Tags: 12.04, wireless, realtek

I've been using Ubuntu for a few weeks now, and since then I've been unable to solve my wireless problem. Every time time I run some intense networking like DL and streaming my wireless crashes, or if I just give it enough time it crash as well.  My only option is to reboot my computer. I've been trying a bunch of different solutions to no avail.

Here what I get when I run `iwconfig`  when it's still working :

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"freebox_ISPCGS"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.452 GHz  Access Point: 00:24:D4:63:66:64   
          Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-35 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

MY computer is a  Compaq Presario CQ56 with a RTL8191SEvA Wireless LAN Controller

Comment: please help me !

Comment: For 8187SE, the best answer on [this link](http://askubuntu.com/a/216123/106827) may help you.Don't forget to change commands and to download your windows driver.

Answer (score 3):

This is a confirmed bug. It affects me also. See here...

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1000208

11.10 is fine. 12.04.1 has this issue when under load the wifi will disconnect and pc needs a reboot. Windows 7 is ok. Load via a speedtest or torrent for example.