# How to resolve wireless disconnect problem in Atheros ath9k

Tags: 12.04, wireless, atheros, ath9k

I have a non stopped problem in my **Acer Aspire 5733 model** using **Atheros** `ath9k` driver. WiFi is working when router is in nearby location, there is nothing updates by Acer for Linux. I also using `rfkill list all` command to check switches, it shows:

```
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

I searched everywhere on Ubuntu forum but didn't find any result for Aspire 5733, also I couldn't found any firmware for Atheros like Broadcom. This is a big disadvantage of Acer with Ubuntu. 
Also, I do some stuff to resolve this problem is to create a file named `ath9k.conf`:

```
/etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
```

with the contents:

```
options ath9k nohwcrypt=1
```

Please suggest me optimal solution for this problem.

Answer (score 4):

Beside creating a file named `/etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf` with the contents options `ath9k nohwcrypt=1`, I also had to disable `acer_wmi` kernel module:

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

and add this line:

```
blacklist acer-wmi
```

Then reboot. This fixed WiFi problems for me.

Comment: It did not work for me (Acer TravelMate 5735Z, Linux Mint 15 (Ubuntu 13.04)).

Comment: This solution also worked for Fedora 31 on a Acer Aspire 4750

Answer (score 2):

I know it's bit old question, but this solution bellow may help other people stuck with ath9k driver on Acer laptops.

Try to compile ath9k driver following this procedure on [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2197316)

Steps:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential
```

Download this to your desktop [backports-3.12.2-1.tar.bz2](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v3.12.2/backports-3.12.2-1.tar.bz2)

Compile using bellow comands

```
cd ~/Desktop/backports-3.12.2-1/
make defconfig-ath9k
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe -r ath9k && sudo modprobe ath9k
```

Your wireless should be working now. Note this will work until next kernel update. After kernel update you will need to recompile the driver again.
Command are similar to ones above.

```
cd ~/Desktop/backports-3.12.2-1/
make clean
make defconfig-ath9k
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe -r ath9k && sudo modprobe ath9k
```

Answer (score 1):

I had problems with the Atheros `ath9k` driver when I upgraded my kernel to fix some power management issues.

Tried the `ath9k.conf` file but it did not work.

Then I downloaded a driver and it solved my WiFi problems. This was what I did:

Go to [wireless.kernel.org](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Download/stable/) and download the appropiate driver for your kernel.

Check kernel version in terminal: `uname -a`

Unpack the file you just downloaded in a new folder into your downloads folder. 
(it should be something like `Downloads/compat-wireless-3.5.4-1-snp`) 

(**beware: your filename might be different**)

You will probably need the build tools; open a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic
```

Then after you have installed `build-essential` and headers, please do:

```
cd Downloads/compat-wireless-3.5.4-1-snp
sudo su
make
make install
modprobe -r ath9k
modprobe ath9k
exit
```

My computer crashed shortly after the 2nd `modprobe`, but when I restarted everything ran lightspeed.

I'm running on an Aspire 5750Z. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This probably won't help for the original question. But, for those using newer versions of Ubuntu, the package `firmware-ath9k-htc` is available. Solved my wireless issue by simply installing it & restarting.

My system is an older MacBook Pro (around 2007 or 2008 I believe) with Ubuntu-MATE 19.04.

```
$ lspci
...
b:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR5418 Wireless Network Adapter [AR5008E 802.11(a)bgn] (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the "WPA group rekey interval" on your wifi router.. this is working for me now.. it was set to 2 before I changed it to 3600. This value is in seconds.. This is working for me now,I tried disabling hardware encryption and power mangagement, but that did not work..

I am now trying other combinations..by enabling power mangement and hardware encryption on again and by lowering the interval time to 60 seconds.. as these are desirable for security :)

Answer (score 0):

Well It is certainly not a optimal solution but a workaround, but what works for me is to request dhcp in a loop i.e.

```
watch -n5 sudo dhclient -v wlan0
```

Then I have intermittent connection via wireless router.
I am using Hp ProBook 4540s and Linksys WRT 54GL

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try to ndiswrapper, it allows you to run windows drivers in linux. Check out previously asked question here [Need a few reboots to connect to wireless](https://askubuntu.com/questions/214085/need-a-few-reboots-to-connect-to-wireless)