# Wifi runs well with Other router other than Netgear

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, internet, atheros

I have sony vaio laptop with ubuntu 14.04 installed on it. My machine connects to `netgear` router but can't load any data from it. like i can't

> ping google.com

It gives me 100% packet loss. and also no site is loaded in browser also

But when I connect to some other router it runs well like `TP-link`. What must be the problem. What my friend said is there must be problem in `encryption` . I unable to understand what may be the reason . I have googled a lot. But didn't find any solution to this.

`lspi -knn | grep Net -A2`

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280] : Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)
 Subsystem : Foxconn Interntional , Inc Device [105b: e044]
 kernel driver in use : ath9k
```

This is what I did encryption by following some post on stack

```
echo 'options ath9k nohwcrypt=1' sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
```

**EDIT**

Now I have upgraded to 14.10 but still the problem is same. My mobile and other laptops running Windows OS can access internet. But what is the problem with ubuntu.??

**edit**

> ifconfig -a

[image: image to the output]

When I ping 192.168.1.1 it gives

```
Destination  host unreachable
```

> Also when I log into netgear router from another pc *sometimes* does not list my laptop connected to the router but what my laptop shows is it is connected to the router.Since it shows the dialog box and contents are `connected to wifi name`

**edit**

When I log in to router from my friends computer which has windows os on it. It works fine and also the address is `192.168.1.1`. The issue I think is with my laptop only because in hostel same problem happens for `all netgear routers` that I have discussed above.

**edit**
 I did kept no security for router but still the problem persists

Comment: Is it your Netgear router? Can you enter setup interface for the router and look what encryption is set there? Also please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: I see. But you did not answer regarding encryption. The driver is OK.

Comment: I meant what encryption is set in your router.

Comment: Can you add the output of `ifconfig -a`?

Comment: I think this is because the router assigned statics IPs and you set your config to DHCP or the other way around.

Comment: Use try using NDISwrapper. I have never done that before, so I cannot write an answer. See [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/Ndiswrapper).

Comment: @daltonfury42 added output of `ifconfig -a`

Comment: Your `ifconfig` output shows over 100 packets were sent and received over `wlan0`, your wfi. Try pinging a known IP address (eg google.com for me is `216.58.211.78`). Try pinging the netgear itself (probably `192.168.1.1`).

Comment: @meuh question updated

Comment: If you can't ping your router you likely have the wrong address for it. Please confirm that your router address is correct (192.168.1.1). [edit] your question to include this confirmation which you are obtaining by logging into the router from another PC whether you are using DHCP or static addressing on your client. Anything that happens "sometimes" requires more information like "if I do this it does/doesn't show"

Comment: @ElderGeek question updated please do check!!

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up. You may find this helpful: http://askubuntu.com/questions/224619/how-to-resolve-wireless-disconnect-problem-in-atheros-ath9k

Comment: Are you sure that your connection is set to use DHCP, and that there is a DHCP server running on the router?

Comment: I owned a Sony Vaio and also had issues with some wireless routers not working and some working. The most likely cause I determined of my laptop was that if the router had only wireless g or an older type of wireless, then my computer failed to connect or work.

Comment: @Daniel Yes connection is set to DHCP

Comment: So this particular laptop has never been able to connect?

Comment: Or just this laptop using Ubuntu can't connect?

Comment: Before 1st hard reset of router this laptop with ubuntu was working good with netgear router. but after hard reset this problem started @Daniel

Comment: So then it's a router config issue

Comment: okay but this happens to all netgear router in my hostel which are not hard reseted once also @Daniel

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25666/discussion-between-daniel-and-suraj-palwe).

Answer (score 0):

Failure to ping google.com by name only indicates a DNS problem. Failure to ping by address indicates a connection problem. If I traceroute to google.com I get an address of 216.58.216.238 (likely one of many servers in the farm - the readers traceroute will vary).

If you can't ping google.com but can ping 216.58.216.238 you have an issue with DNS which you can likely resolve by changing the DNS server config in your router (assuming DHCP configuration for your client. Make these changes in the client configuration instead if using static IP addressing) Google public DNS server is at 8.8.8.8 as I recall your ISP can provide you with their DNS server address(es).

Being unable to ping 192.168.1.1 indicates that you may not be using the correct address as configured in the Netgear router. This address can be changed in the router configuration which can be [reset to factory defaults](http://kb.netgear.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/9665/~/restoring-a-netgear-home-router-to-the-factory-default-settings) if it's been mucked up beyond your ability to fix. It's also possible to disable wireless configuraton of the router. Use a Ethernet cable rather than wifi to [access the router](http://kb.netgear.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1148/~/default-web-interface-password-for-netgear-devices) after restoring to default settings and set it up properly from scratch.

**NOTE:** Make sure you know the security type (encryption level)  in use before resetting as well as the wireless passcode or you'll end up having to reconfigure every client on the network (good practice perhaps, but avoidable with a bit of pre-planning in most cases)

Comment: I cannot ping 216.58.216.238 also. It gives me 100% packet loss .. and also see the edited question

Comment: clearly you have a connection issue. What happens if you connect via a known good ethernet cable?

Answer (score 0):

doubt netgear has something to do with it.
i use netgear router and it works just fine with ubuntu, but i have a different wireless card.

try checking additional drivers in dash menu, if you can use other driver for your wi-fi - try it.

also try checking is your IP4 address currently used by a windows machine within same network, i saw some problems with embedded in wi-fi DHCP`s when there are different OS computers in same network.

another thing you can try is installing different software on your wi-fi router, like DD-WRT or Tomato.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I will give a try to some other softwares !!